# How do i choose boot option on pc start

Tags: arch-linux, boot, windows, dual-boot, bios

I have both Arch Linux and Windows installed on my PC. Linux is on one drive, and Windows is on another.

Is it possible to choose the boot option when my PC starts, or do I always need to open the BIOS and select it from there?

Comment: No bootmanager like grub or etc..?

Comment: Don't know the answer to this but when you installed arch Linux did you have the option to install grub ? If so then it should have made a entry in grub so when you boot up it should have arch and windows. You might need to boot back into the installer (USB stick/iso) and re-run grub. There are some YouTube videos out there with grub windows and arch Linux

Comment: I recommend installing ReFind boot manager. It's a ton easier to configure than GRUB or Windows Boot Manager. After installing it to `/boot/efi` (EFI System Partition aka ESP), just make it default using `efibootmgr`. It's not signed unfortunately, so if you have secure boot enabled, you'll need to configure either GRUB or Windows Boot Manager.